# How does Mathematica know my location?

Tags: curated-data, geography

On the [`AstronomicalData` page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AstronomicalData.html) in the online reference, it says for

```
AstronomicalData["Sun", "NextRiseTime"]
```

that it finds the next rise time for the Sun **from your current location** and time. Where does *Mathematica* keep that? I don't remember giving that during installation and I can't find it in the Preferences either.

**edit**
Particularly the returned value

```
{2012, 9, 5, 7, 3, 52.704}
```

to 1 ms resolution suggests that the location is known to some precision. At the latitude where I live, 1 ms is 25 cm.

Comment: You've seen `FindGeoLocation[]` and `$GeoLocation`?

Comment: @J.M. - I have now :-), thanks. But it doesn't answer my question: `FindGeoLocation may use built-in GPS or other capabilities`. My PC doesn't have a GPS, and I don't know if an IP-address will tell much.

Comment: See for example http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db5-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude

Comment: @stevenvh IP adresses and the routes to them can tell quite a lot. http://www.geoiptool.com/

Comment: You'll find a lot of info in this site http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23922/how-does-ip-geocoding-work

Comment: Regarding precision: a question posted yesterday show that the world land area is reported with an error the size of New Zealand, so don't bet in that ms accuracy ...

Comment: @belisarius - The difference between resolution and accuracy! ;-) From a software like Mathematica I had expected better. Why add the `0.704` if even the 7 is probably wrong?

Comment: @stevenvh because most users never saw one of these http://sliderulemuseum.com/Nestler.htm

Comment: @belisarius uhhh, lovely hardware!

Comment: You can type "where am I" into Wolfram|Alpha to see the sources of information that Wolfram might use for geo-location. Unfortunately, my IP address is the location of my ISP's computers, more than 300 miles to the east, yet WolframAlpha has specified a Longitude of 7 degrees West, firmly in the Atlantic Ocean. Glug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As comments have stated, in most cases `FindGeoLocation` (and in turn other functions based on your geographical localization) use a so-called GeoIP service (similar to, e.g., [this one](http://www.geoiptool.com)) to determine to some extent your localization. This can be confirmed by using `Trace` on `FindGeoLocation`, which shows that Mathematica calls home to a Wolfram server for this purpose:

```
http://dataserver.wolfram.com/GeoIPLookup/GeoIPLookupServlet?l=Lxxxx-xxxx&m=yyyy-yyyyy-yyyyy&s=MacOSX-x86-64&lang=English
```

where `Lxxxx-xxxx` is your licence number and `yyyy-yyyyy-yyyyy` is your machine ID.

This can also be confirmed, in my case, by switching off the WiFi access: `FindGeoLocation[]` then returns `Missing["NotAvailable"]`, as documented.

Comment: The only purpose of including your license number and machine ID is to check whether you are a legit user, right?  Geo=location would not require this information.

Comment: @DavidCarraher I doubt it... it's probably more to track your usage and for an internal account of what functions are requesting the geolocation service. If you read the license agreement, they also say that any *Mathematica* web search you perform via the documentation center (I mean the "x matches on Wolfram sites" you get when there isn't an immediate hit within the docs) is fair game for their data mining and the query is sent along with your license number and machine ID. That's how they found out acl likes pink underwear.

Comment: @R.M well, if StackExchange performed the same data mining, they could personalize the top user swag, and acl would then receive heptagon-branded pink underwear…